# hashmap and probing - AVAILABLE and null?

Tags: hashmap, linear-probing

In linear probing there is a special value called `AVAILABLE` which is replaced when items are removed.

And when you are inserting a key you look for a empty cell (this just means the cell is `null`?) or one that contains `AVAILABLE`, what I don't understand is if the empty cell means `null` instead of having the special value `AVAILABLE` why not just make the cell `null`?

What is the advantage over using `AVAILABLE`?

Comment: Can you give a reference to where you got the "AVAILABLE" term? Maybe it is a quirk from academia.

Comment: @usr yes, [here](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CC/225/jmanuch/lec/12-3.ppt) it is on slide 10, the comments on the code

Comment: Hm I have no idea. At least according to the code shown null and AVAILABLE are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In closed hashing (open addressing) a value is looked up as:

1. Compute key hash and from it determine the "perfect" bucket;
2. If the bucket is occupied and has key equal to the one looked up, return the value;
3. If the bucket is not occupied, abort the lookup with a failure;
4. Go to the next bucket (with linear probing just increment bucket index) and step 2.

Now, suppose you start looking up in bucket 5 and find your key only in bucket 8.  If erasing procedure now marked bucket 6 as unoccupied, you'd never get to bucket 8 due to step 3.  Therefore, we need a special value that marks bucket as "occupied", yet still available for insertion.  This is probably what your source terms as `AVAILABLE`, and `null` as unoccupied at all.

**EDIT:** BTW, with linear probing it is possible to (quite) efficiently get away without this special `AVAILABLE` value, but that complicates erasing considerably.